# How to specify mySQL host when creating the database locally?

Tags: mysql, database, windows, host

When connecting to a mysqldatabase, oftentimes you'll use --host=somehost. When creating a database locally using mySQL's Windows installer, how do you specify that? Is it possible?

I want to clarify that I want to be able to customize it - so, for instance, I want it to be something like "CUSTOMNAME-HOST" and not just "localhost"

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible by changing hosts file from your operating system.

If you are using windows operating system then 
Open your OS installation Directory then:`Windows>System32>drivers>etc`

Then open your hosts file and change it to `127.0.0.1       localhost`  to

```
127.0.0.1        CUSTOMNAME-HOST
```

Save it.